# Volume Capacity By Taking The Average Of Right And Left-Endpoint Approximations

Tags: calculus, volume

In a problem regarding volumes of revolution, we are asked to estimate the volume capacity of the bowl shown by taking the average of right- and left-endpoint approximations to the integral with $N=7$. We are given the inner radii starting from the top $0, 4, 7, 8, 10, 13, 14, 20$, and these two graphs, 
[image]

In the solutions manual, starting with the right-endpoint, 
$$R_{7}=3\pi \left((23^{2}-14^{2})+(25^{2}-13^{2})+(26^{2}-10^{2})+(27^{2}-8^{2})+(28^{2}-7^{2})+(29^{2}-4^{2})+(30^{2}-0^{2}) \right)=13470\pi$$

I am not asking for the full solution, I want to understand what did we exactly do here? Where did the $3\pi$ come from? And where did we get values such as $23$ and $26$.. etc? What do we mean by $23^{2}-14^{2}$? What does this represent?

I am confused because the textbook did not solve a similar problem where we used average of right and left-endpoint approximations. There is no solved example I can understand from.

Comment: I think the idea is that we slice the geometry in the vertical direction. Now all the slices look like flat circles with a hole in the center. Therefore, each cirle has an inner radius and an outer radius. Of course, the area of one slice (in the $xz$-plane) is
$$
A_{\text{slice}} = \pi  R_{\text{outer}}^2 - \pi R_{\text{inner}}^2
$$. If you look at the terms closely, you will see that the differences of the squared terms are indeed these values.

Comment: The top slice doesn't have a hole, so it's just (omitting the $\pi$) $30^2 - 0^2$. The slice below it has an outer radius of $30-1 = 29$ and inner radius of $4$ (as indicated by you). Note that $4+25+1=30$; $25$ is equal to $R_{\text{outer}}-R_{\text{inner}}$. So these are the last two terms in the expression.

Comment: @MattiP. The values in the graph represent the difference between the outer and inner radius. What I noticed we have $R_{\text{outer}}- 4 = 25$ will give us $R_{outer}=29$.. so what we are doing is $R_{outer}-R_{inner}= 29-4$.. but I don't understand why are they squared? And where did we get $3\pi $ from exactly?

Comment: @MattiP. I just realized because they represent circles which is why we would square them. But I am confused about the $3\pi$?

Comment: Isn't 3 just the "height" of each slice? (assuming the 7 slices have the same height of course)

Comment: @ensbana you mean since we already have height of $21$, we divide it by $7$, and thus get $3$? I thought of that but was not sure if it is correct or just a coincidence

Comment: To convince yourself, I suggest you look at the formula in the solution, expand it out as the sum of the terms $h(\pi R^2_{outer} - \pi R^2_{inner})$, see what each term represents and why it has that particular form. To give you an idea, try to think of the approximation as 7 round wooden boards on top of each other, each with a hole in the middle. The problem would become finding and summing up the volumes of those boards.